# Matrix inverse function of Eigen library returns NaN

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

This is a new created example having the same problem.
The 2 matrices "firstMultiplyMat" , "a " are having the same values, but specified in different ways. Nevertheless, the inverse of each one is different. Cannot get inverse for "firstMultiplyMat" whereas "a" has correct calculated inverse matrix.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <Eigen/Core> 
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;

struct MemberLocation{
int id;
double x;
double y;
};

int main(){

//Attributes
int M = 2 ;//anchor
int N = 2 ;//nonanchor
int NA = 4;
int p = 0;
int numOfIterations =2;
MemberLocation *member1 = new MemberLocation[M];
MemberLocation *member2 = new MemberLocation[N];
MatrixXd neighbourdistanceEst(M,N);
MatrixXd neighbourdistanceDeriv(M,NA);
MatrixXd distanceDerivTranspose(NA,M);
MatrixXd firstMultiplyMat(NA,NA);
MatrixXd firstMultiplyMatInverse(NA,NA);

//Structs initilaization
member1[0].id = 5;
member1[0].x = 9.31301;
member1[0].y = 19.3955;

member1[1].id = 2;
member1[1].x = 46.6279;
member1[1].y = 0.00571905;

member2[0].id = 4;
member2[0].x = 11.7718;
member2[0].y = 7.99507;

member2[1].id = 6;
member2[1].x = 23.6158;
member2[1].y = 3.80408;

// Filling "neighbourdistanceDeriv" matrix
for (int i = 1 ; i <  numOfIterations ; i++ ){

for (int j = 0 ; j < M ; j++){
for (int k = 0 ; k < N ; k++){

    int id1 = member2[k].id; 
    int id2 = member1[j].id; 
    double xDiff = member2[k].x - member1[j].x; 
    double yDiff = member2[k].y - member1[j].y;
    double distance = pow(xDiff,2) + pow(yDiff,2);           

    neighbourdistanceEst(j,k) = sqrt(distance);

    neighbourdistanceDeriv(j,p) = xDiff / neighbourdistanceEst(j,k);
    neighbourdistanceDeriv(j,p+1) = yDiff / neighbourdistanceEst(j,k);

    p+=2;

}
p = 0;
}
}

// operations on "neighbourdistanceDeriv" matrix
distanceDerivTranspose = neighbourdistanceDeriv.transpose();
firstMultiplyMat = distanceDerivTranspose*neighbourdistanceDeriv;
firstMultiplyMatInverse = firstMultiplyMat.inverse();

// printing "firstMultiplyMat" matrix and its inverse
std::cout << "firstMultiplyMat:\n" << firstMultiplyMat << std::endl;
std::cout << "inverse of firstMultiplyMat:\n" << firstMultiplyMatInverse << std::endl<< std::endl;

// fixed array with same values obtained in "neighbourdistanceDeriv" matrix at runtime
MatrixXd a(4,4);
MatrixXd b(4,4);
a(0,0) =  0.994532;
a(0,1) =   -0.423853;
a(0,2)=  1.10423 ;
a(0,3) =    -0.314096;
a(1,0) = -0.423853 ;
a(1,1) = 1.00547 ;
a(1,2) =   -0.881237 ;
a(1,3) =  0.756726 ;
a(2,0) = 1.10423 ;
a(2,1) =   -0.881237;
a(2,2) =   1.43045;
a(2,3) =   -0.658827;
a(3,0) = -0.314096;
a(3,1) =  0.756726  ;
a(3,2) =  -0.658827;
a(3,3) = 0.569549 ;
b = a.inverse();
std::cout << "matrix a :\n" << a <<std::endl;
std::cout << "inverse of matrix a :\n" << b << std::endl;
//std::cout<<"hi \n";
return 0;
}
```

---

The output :

```
firstMultiplyMat:
0.994534 -0.423857   1.10423 -0.314099
-0.423857   1.00547 -0.881237  0.756725
1.10423 -0.881237   1.43045 -0.658827
-0.314099  0.756725 -0.658827  0.569548
inverse of firstMultiplyMat:
-nan -nan -nan -nan
-nan -nan -nan -nan
-nan -nan -nan -nan
-nan -inf -inf  inf

matrix a :
0.994532 -0.423853   1.10423 -0.314096
-0.423853   1.00547 -0.881237  0.756726
1.10423 -0.881237   1.43045 -0.658827
-0.314096  0.756726 -0.658827  0.569549
inverse of matrix a :
-119414     -1681.81       132361      89489.1
-1681.81       942762      10176.4 -1.24175e+06
132361      10176.4      -146638      -110149
89489.1 -1.24175e+06      -110149  1.57177e+06
```

Comment: Can you show the code where neighbourdistanceDeriv and firstMultiplyMat are declared and initialized?

Comment: code is added to the post

Comment: I wasn't able to get your example using a(4,4) to misbehave by replacing the 4s with a variable (eg, a(N,N)). Please post a concise program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I understand you, i edited the post with the whole part of specifying the matrix values, so you can test it. 
I hope this can help you figure out the problem for me.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: randa, your example is not concise. Create an example that someone can just copy and paste in to a file, run, and see the problem.

Comment: i created a new example showing the problem.

Comment: You left out the definition of MemberLocation, so it doesn't compile.

Comment: I am sorry there was aproblem in posting,will add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix firstMultiplyMat itself is fine memory-wise; if you push the values into it that you had put into a, it'll invert correctly. Your problem lies in the values that are inside firstMultiplyMat, which are not *exactly* the same values as what get printed, because what is printed is truncated.

Essentially, your matrix may not be invertible. You can work around this by just not computing the inverse and instead using a QR solver, eg:

```
HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr(A);
x = qr.solve(b); // computes A^-1 * b
```

More information about HouseholderQR is available [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1HouseholderQR.html)

Comment: i am using the constructor MatrixXd(rows,cols).
Code of declaration of matrices is added to the post.

Comment: Aha i got the point of truncating, but how could i check the correctness of my results? cannot i stop truncation so that i could calculate and compare the results on online matrix calculator?
Also, aren't there any difference between calculating inverse using inverse and qr decomposition - i mean mathematically- are both correct and equal? i tried qr decomposition and it gave me results, but i am so confused now. I cannot know if my results are correct or not and how to make sure before i complete coding my next part of work?
Thx again for your help

Comment: This may help. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109329/can-qr-decomposition-be-used-for-matrix-inversion The code in this answer doesn't give you the inverse of A. It helps you compute x without having to invert A at all.

Comment: Thanks alot. I have one final small question:is their any possibility that the data of the matrix in memory is having a problem? I mean what could be truncated in printing except some digits after the 5 appearing digits after the point. Does these little digits change alot the inverse to be able to be calculated or not?or change the values of the inverse alot between 2 matrices if the inverse can be calculated for both?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. I can tell you that I tried filling firstMultiplyMat with the values that you had put into a, right before taking its inverse, and without changing any of the other code, and I got a "correct" answer. So that leads me to believe that the memory is fine and those truncated digits matter. Best I can advise is to assume that matrix inversion may be problematic for this particular data and just avoid it by use of QR or another mathematical workaround.